# Can Hyper-V run on AMD Ryzen processors?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, amd-ryzen

Is it possible to run Hyper-V under Windows 10 on AMD Ryzen processors (specifically a 1600)

Windows allowed me to install the Hyper-V service and create guests, but trying to start a guest produces the following error -

> Virtual machine 'Test' could not be started because the hypervisor is not running

Looking around the net I don't seem to be able to find any firm confirmation.

Comment: This entirely depends if Ryzen processors have the appropriate AMD virtualization extension required to run Hyper-V.  Is this the case?  **Hyper-V supports the appropriate AMD and Intel virtualization technology x86 extensions.**  If a VM that requires these extensions isn't working then the hardware feature isn't enabled in the firmware settings more then likely.

Comment: You need to hit the little green start button to actually boot the VM. Simply double clicking a VM inside of Hyper-V manager doesn't turn on the VM it only opens the VM in an off state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two aspects to consider here:

- CPU Virtualization.  Ryzen chips absolutely support this, and in fact I don't know of any modern AMD chips that don't except for the absolute cheapest APU's.  I've been running VM's utilizing this (QEMU+KVM for those who may care) with no issues for quite some time.  This can however be disabled in the system firmware, and most systems have it disabled by default (the same is true on Intel) for security reasons.
- IOMMU support.  I'm not sure if Hyper-V needs this or not, but every other type-1 Hypervisor I know of does, so I assume Hyper-V does as well.  This is a property of the chipset.  I know that the X370 chipset has an IOMMU, and I think that the X300 chipset does too, but I'm not sure about the A or B series chipsets.  Just like CPU Virtualization, this can usually be disabled in the BIOS, and usually is by default.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using a Gigabyte AX370 board, which probably isn't the prime choice for virtualisation, but it does work.

Hyper-V would not install until I enabled virtualisation in the BIOS. At this point I was able to install the feature but not start a virtual machine, receiving the error as in my original question.

Turns out there's an additional option in the BIOS to turn on SVM hidden away under "Advanced Frequency Settings", then "Advanced CPU Core Settings". Not sure why it's under frequency settings rather than in the main CPU features list with the other virtualisation option, but everything works fine once they're both enabled.

Comment: You may add the screenshot of that bios setting to enrich your answer.

Comment: @USDMatt Please post photos of your BIOS screens.

Comment: I have enabled this and IOMMU (which is found under "Chipset"). I can now start the hypervisor.

Comment: My setting was listed under Overclocking > CPU Features as "SVM Mode"

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you have the Hyper-V management software running, but the underlying Hyper-V infrastructure is not running.  Hyper-V is a type-1 hypervisor, so the software that you're using in Windows is just a console; the actual Hyper-V important stuff is loaded before your OS loads.

1. Be sure SVM is enabled in BIOS.  You should verify it is on in BIOS, but also in Task Manager ... click the Performance tab, click the CPU, and in the bottom-right area, you'll see "Virtualization:" ... make sure it says "Enabled".  If it says "Disabled", and you have SVM enabled in BIOS, then I'm not sure what your issue is.
2. If virtualization wasn't enabled, or it disabled itself somewhere along the way, you might have to uninstall Hyper-V and reinstall it.  This I'm not sure about, but if you turn off SVM and try to boot to a virtualized system, Windows PROBABLY uninstalls it and makes the host OS just a simple installation of Windows.  I'd doubt it will re-enable it acutomatically, which might be the situation you're in.

I've been running Hyper-V on my Ryzen system (Gigabtye B350 board) for about 3 months.  Everything works awesome EXCEPT you can't run x86 versions of Windows in virtual machines; there is a VME bug that AMD claims to have fixed, but they didn't.

Edit: As well, make sure you don't have any other virtualization software running on your system; these can create a litany of weird issues.

Comment: Is that bug fixed? I am a little heistant of buying AMD just for the compatibility, willing to spend a little more on Intel for that. So I am wondering whether it is still an issue. I would like to run some old 32bit VMs.

Answer (score 2):

I tried running Hyper-V on my Windows 10 Pro 64 bit system with a Ryzen 7 2700X and an MSI X470 motherboard, but was having issues. I enabled virtualization support on my processor but even then it would not run properly (*grrr*). The VM would start, and hang and would keep "running" but not execute further.

I went into the BIOS and changed some settings. Not sure which one did the trick, but I changed simultaneous multithreading from auto to enabled, switched my VRAM/GPU settings to 64 bit enable and another obscure advanced setting that I don't recall.

Bottom line, Virtualization on my system appears to be operating normally after I made the changes. Go into your BIOS and enable anything that *might* affect virtualization, and it could help you troubleshoot your issue. Yes, it's a shot in the dark but sometimes it's what you have to do to solve your issue.

Comment: On older RyzenCPUs, limiting the # of cores to 1 will band-aid the problem. My 5900x does not have this limitation, but I am not sure if that is a fix AMD made on this generation of CPUs, or if Microsoft fixed something in Hyper-V (I no longer have my older CPUs to test).